# Using PostgreSQL installed in Windows inside WSL as well?

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed PostgreSQL version 10 in Windows. Since I'm doing Web development work and using WSL frequently I would like to use PostgreSQL from within WSL too.

Is there anyway in which we are able to link the PostgreSQL software installed in Windows with WSL environment so that any new databases created inside WSL is available in the Windows environment also?

1) PostgreSQL10 installed on Windows environment.

2) PostgresSQL9.5 installed inside WSL environment.

My Question is: how do I connect both Windows configurations WSL to use the same PostgreSQL instance?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I mean the windows Subsystem for Linux .

Comment: Both are the same mentioned. No two different environment.

Comment: You have two servers on the same system? One in Windows and one in WSL? Why? One server, many clients would make more sense. Just connect to localhost on whatever port your windows server instance is listening. Or perhaps I'm missing something here.